# Combine 4 short JavaScript form validations into one script

Tags: javascript, validation

I don't know java but this looks easy for someone who does. I need to validate a contact form and I have these validation scripts but they don't run if I enter multiple instances of this script, works fine if just one of them is used. Can someone combine these 4 into one validation script.

**Validate Name Field**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

**Validate Subject Field**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["subject"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Subject must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

**Validate Message Field**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Message must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

**Validate Email Field**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

**And your typical contact form**

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="subject">
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: javascript is not the same as a java script. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470971/Java-vs-JavaScript.htm

Comment: Surely you can see the similarities in these scripts. Why not try combining them yourself first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got it work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;if (x==null || x==""){alert("Name must be filled out");return false}
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;var atpos=x.indexOf("@");var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length){alert("Not a valid e-mail address");return false;}
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["subject"].value;if (x==null || x==""){alert("Subject must be filled out");return false}
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value;if (x==null || x==""){alert("Message must be filled out");return false}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like;

```
var validation = ["name","subject","message","email"];   
validation.forEach(
    x=document.forms["myForm"][this];
    if(this=="email"){
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length){
             alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
             return false;
        }
   }else{
        if (this==null || x==""){
            alert(this.toUpperCase()." must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: That didn't work but thanks for helping. After much trial and error and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work in one function using the conditional "if", calling the function with the submit event in the form, i think its simpliest and easier than you think, this an example of a simple form:

```
<form action="insert.php" name="contact" onsubmit="return valida_frm(this)" method="post">

               <input name="personname" type="text"/>
               <input name="personemail" type="email"/>                  
               <textarea name="message"></textarea>
               <input type="submit" value="Send">

            </form>
```

Then you add the function between the "head" tags

```
<script language="javascript">
function valida_frm(form){
var alert="Error:\n";
if (form.personname.value == "") {alert+="Name can't be empty.\n";} 
if (form.personemail.value == "") {alert+="E-Mail can't be empty.\n";}
if (form.message.value == "") {alert+="Message can't be empty.\n";}
if (alert!="Error:\n"){
    alert(alert);   
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}   
}
</script>
```

You can use this way to validate and send the input values to your mailer. I hope this help you.